# library not found for -lFirebaseAuth clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I have added Firebase to my podfile and pod installed. Get the error above. 
I then delete PodFile and Podfile.lock and try again. Same error. 
Did again but first did pod repo update. And again with pod update then pod install. Same error
Added all Firebase to my Linker Library and same Error.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
target 'myApp' do
    pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.27.3'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
end
```

All answers on Stackoverflow say open .workspace instead or project. I am doing this and same error.

Is there a chance something was edited when someone opened the project file instead of the workspace file?

Not sure where to go from here.